# JS rewrite every href links by ID

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, url-rewriting, href

I have a page with `<a>` tag links directing to JS script (modal windows), but if someone came and has JS turned off, this page won't work.. so I want to make it functionally for both case, JS on and off..

Here's an idea for rewriting "href" links with JS script..

JS off:

```
<a id="first" href="main.php?page=something">Link</a>
```

JS on:

```
<a id="first" href="#something">Link</a>
```

I try this:

```
<a id="first" href="main.php?page=something">Link</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("first").href= "#something";
</script>
```

but this only add "#something" to file name (example: if file is named something.php, URL  gonna be "something.php#something") and not rewrite it..

any suggest for something really simple ? working on ID's, because there are several links need to be rewrited.. and no jQuery pls..

Comment: What you're doing is in fact the correct thing to do. When you code an `<a>` tag *without* JavaScript with an "href" like "#something", if you later check the value of the "href" property it will be a complete URL. That's what a "#something" URL means, after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean? Using your example it rewrites it to #something not something.php#something...

```
document.getElementById("first").href= "#something";
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bowenac/hb349/)

Comment: It was an answer to his own question which he answered himself. How is this not an answer?

Comment: I must admit, I don't check this script on real situation, only as a test.. after this comment I test it on real page, and it's really works.. I'm sorry, long and hard day for me.. thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try.

```
for (var i = 0, links = document.links; i < links.length; ++i) {
    if (links[i].search.indexOf("page=") > -1)
        links[i].href = "#" + links[i].search.split("page=")[1].split("&")[0]
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CByhw/

Comment: if I'm not wrong, this change every href to #something ? if this is it, so that's not what I want..

Comment: @TichomírDuchaplný: No, of course not. It'll change every `href` that has a `page=` query parameter into the value of that parameter for that link. The way you're doing it, you need to hardcode every change, and hope you never make a mistake. Here's another demo http://jsfiddle.net/CByhw/1/

Comment: this is cool, but little tricky.. I have several links and they are not corresponding (I hope this is right word).. simply for example: link is ?page=login and JS variant is #singup.. but maybe in another project, I'm gonna use this, thanks..

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to add `click` event to all links which should display modal dialogs.

*HTML:*

```
<a href="main.php?page=something" data-modal="something">Link</a>
```

*JavaScript:*

```
var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a[data-modal]');
for (var i = 0, len = anchors.length; i < len; i++) {
    anchors[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        var modal = this.getAttribute('data-modal');
        showModal(document.getElementById(modal));
        e.preventDefault();
    }, false);
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/wE3NC/